# Two theorems about absolute continuity, what am I missing? Since one is much nicer than the other.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Look at these two theorems:

[image]

and

[image]

It seems to me that the second theorem is much better than the first since we don't need to check the condition $f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t)$. And also every pointwise derivative is a weak derivative. So for the second theorem all we need is $f'$ to exist weakly and a.e. The only extra thing for the second theorem seems to be that $f$ needs to be locally integrable. Is that really it? What am I missing?

Comment: Every pointwise derivative is a weak derivative? What happens if you apply that to the Cantor function? I think you will find that the weak derivative can be a quite tricky concept.

Comment: @assa888 : The first one requires you to check integral conditions over all intervals. The second one requires that you verify an infinity of integral conditions over an entire class of functions. You really only need the integral conditions for piecewise linear functions in order to get $f(x)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)\,dt$ after taking a limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Harald Hanche-Olsen said, the statement "Every pointwise derivative is a weak derivative?" is false.  The term "weak derivative" might suggest somehow unsatisfying, barely acceptable object -- but in fact, this concept captures what we need to get analysis started (fundamental theorem of calculus). It's the pointwise (a.e.) derivative  that turns out to be awkward in comparison, and inadequate for objects such as the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

The condition $f(x)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)\,dt$ [i.e., the validity of the fundamental theorem of calculus] is what qualifies a pointwise derivative to be a weak derivative; perhaps not as a primary definition, but as an equivalent form of it.